# Change an input fields background-color on hover (mouseover)

Tags: html, css

I have a form where fields must be populated by user.  When a user hovers over a field I would like it to change color.
I trying to get this working for a single field to begin with.  I have the following CSS:

```
.f2:hover{
    border: 10px solid red; 
    border-top-color: orange; 
    background-color: red;
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

The borders are changing color but the field is not changing color.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with that tiny fragment of code. Try providing a [mcve] (preferably in the form of a live demo in a stack snippet)

Comment: Well, i tried your code on fiddle and it work fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/971nneuc/

Maybe an example of ur code will help us to see the problem

Answer (score 3):

Your css should look like this.

```
.f2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.f2:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

here is a fiddle of it working.

https://jsfiddle.net/wab9na2z/

Next time you make a post add more detail, show us more code, and provide us with more information about your problem. I hope this solves your issue and good luck on the road to learning front end development.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .f2:hover{
      border: 10px solid red; 
      border-top-color: orange;
      background-color: red;
      opacity:1.0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input class="f2" type="text" name="">
    <input class="f2" type="text" name="">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with this, this worked for me. remember put the name class in each input tag, not in form tag.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```css
.f2:hover { border: 2px solid black; background-color: red; opacity:1.0;}
```

```html
<div class="f2">Testing</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP is wanting to change the background color of an input element.